# Thymeleaf post object to controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new to Thymeleaf, I tried to post object to controller but didn't get any success. Here is a form template I am using:

```
<form id="customerRecord" th:action="@{/saveData}" method="post" th:object="${customerData}">
    <input type="hidden" th:value="${name}" th:field="*{name}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Save Record</button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/saveData")
public String saveCustomerData(@ModelAttribute("customerData") CustomerData customerData, Model model) {
    try {
        LOG.info("Working {}", writer.writeValueAsString(customerData));
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        LOG.info("Problem");
    }
    return "success";
}
```

CustomerData class:

```
public class CustomerData {
    private AuthorizeRequestItem name;
    private AuthorizeRequestItem mobileNumber;
    private AuthorizeRequestItem countryCode;
    private AuthorizeRequestItem emailUser;
    private AuthorizeRequestItem emailDomain;
}
```

AuthorizeRequestItem class:

```
public class AuthorizeRequestItem {
    private Date date;
    private String validator;
    private Boolean valid;
    private String data;
}
```

Problem is the `CustomerData` it self contain nested objects.

I need to pass complete `CustomerData` to controller, but when I tried to pass object in input field, it (controller) received a null value for nested objects of `CustomerData`.

I have implemented Thymeleaf forms to pass Objects containing string variable and it is working good for me.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please put your CustomerData class

Comment: i have edited the code. check now,

Comment: @HammadAllauddin I believe you are getting only name from customerData now?

Comment: @manfromnowhere no i am only getting null values

Comment: Ok by bad  i did't see input hidden. may i know why you are making input `type="hidden"` how value will enter if you don't have any values already?

Comment: Thymeleaf expect you to add all the customerData inputs .

Comment: @manfromnowhere we have a table view in our template which displayed customer data using same object we need to send to our controller on submission, this is just a kind of confirmation screen.

Answer (score 0):

This will work,when we are using post in thyme leaf we will use ajax call this will get your value and pass it to your controller now when you click submit button value will be pass to your controller.
For example:

```
 <div id="form Data">
<input  id="app Id" type="hidden" t h:value="${app Id}" />
 <input  type="submit"  on click="redirection()"/>
</div>

<script type='text/java script'>
function redirection(){
 let app id = document.get Element By Id('app Id').value;

 let u r l ="this will be your u r l where you want to redirect"

 window.open(u r l,"_self");
```